# WebGl - Video Texturing stays stucked at first frame

Tags: video, canvas, textures, html5-video, webgl

I am now working on a project that applies a noise dithering on images with WebGL. Now, I wanted to adapt it to video, using videos as texture instead of the old image —witch worked perfectly.
The tutorials examples given by Firefox (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/WebGL/Animating_textures_in_WebGL) works also like a charm.

But, what have to happen always happens: when you try yourself, it never does work - The video stays stucked at the first frame, while the audio starts playing normally. I tried to fix it grabbing some more code from the WebGL Video Demo of Firefox, and then rolling up the Web to find something similar to my problem. So I think it is not really a problem with the video, but yes when WebGL handles the frames. And it seems to be quite structural, because I got no errors when I run it on the Firefox console. I also tried different devices (MacOSX, Ubuntu, Windows 8), with both Firefox and Chrome.

```
var videoElement;

function load() {
    clearInterval(timer);
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

    videoElement = document.getElementById("video");
```

... end of load() function...

```
        drawScene();

        initTexture();

        updateTexture();


        timer = setInterval(fr, 500);
        time = new Date().getTime();
        animation = "animate";
        anim();
    }
```

... declaring texture variables and functions ...

```
var my_texture;

  function initTexture() {
  my_texture = gl.createTexture();
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, my_texture);
  gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);

  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);

  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
}


  function startVideo() {
  videoElement.play();
  intervalID = setInterval(drawScene, 15);
}

function videoDone() {
  clearInterval(intervalID);
}    

  function updateTexture() {
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, my_texture);
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, videoElement);
}
```

I am feeling like the `advance()` and `composite()` functions must be a part of the problem. Of course you can check the whole project in this GitHub repository: https://github.com/crocuta/thequietworld/blob/master/videoshading-0-6.html

Is there anyone who knows what is wrong? The video is an essential part of my project, and I as stucked as the video on it.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling updateTexture at the start of each draw